# How to know e-Wallet with xpub

Tags: blockchain.info, bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed, xpub

How can I know what's e-wallet name provide the wallet?

**When I know xpub and xprv and mnemonic**

*When I get mnemonic (12 words) and get xpub I can get balance with blockchain API*

But how can I know what wallet company provides this wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I know what's e-wallet name provide the wallet (...) When I know xpub and xprv and mnemonic?

You cannot. A mnemonic seed phrase, xpub, and xprv does not explicitly contain information about which wallet software was used to create that wallet. Generally this is not any issue to the user though, as this information alone should be enough** to recover the wallet, using any software which follows similar standards.

** *you may also need information about the derivation path used, and the address type, in case the original wallet did not follow one of the more well-used standards*